# Segmentation fault on array write

Tags: c

I have just started learning C from Ritchie and Kernighan's book. I am trying to reverse a string recursively, however, I get a segmentation fault with this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void reverse (char s[], int l, int r);

int main () {
 
    reverse("hello world", 0, 10);
}
void reverse (char s[], int l, int r) {

    
    int temp = s[l];
    s[l] = s[r];
    s[r] = temp;
    
    if (++l >= --r) {
        return;
    } else {
        reverse (s, ++l, --r);
    }
   
}
```

I'm not sure what im doing wrong, but I found that the segmentation fault occurs at `s[l] = s[r];`

Comment: string literals (which you are passing as `s`) should not be written to. Treat them as read-only. Where do you expect the result to be stored anyway?

Comment: btw, note that you are incrementing/decrementing `l` and `r` *twice* before the recursive call. I think it is not what you want to do.

Comment: yeah thanks i just fixed that

Answer (score 3):

The string you're passing to the function is a **string constant**.  They are immutable, and attempting to change them is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which is why it's crashing.

Create a local array to store the string, then pass that in.

```
int main () {
    char str[] = "hello world";
    reverse(str, 0, 10);
}
```

Comment: ah thanks, im an idiot lol

Comment: String literals aren't constants (nor are they `const`-qualified)